# Variation on knapsack algorithm

Tags: algorithm, optimization, combinatorics, knapsack-problem

I think this might be a variation of the multiple knapsack problem (or maybe even could be reduced to it) but I'm not sure. Here's the problem:

You have a set of items with known values and weights. You also have a set of knapsacks, and each knapsack can hold a fixed number of items (different knapsacks might be able to hold different numbers of items). Maximize total value of items in knapsacks while staying under a given weight.

Note that the individual knapsacks don't have a weight restriction. Each knapsack only has a "number of items it can contain" restriction. The only other restriction is the total weight of the items.

Any ideas?? (other than brute force of course). Thanks in advance! :)

EDIT: one important restriction I forgot to include:

Items can't necessarily be put into any bag. Essentially their value becomes zero if they are put into a bag they aren't compatible with. You can imagine a general case where each item has a value dependent on its bag, but for my case, its value will either be 0 or it's normal value, depending on the bag.

Comment: Is this homework? If so, we should tag is as such. What have you tried?

Comment: Uh - homework? :) Probably gonna get some hate here.

Comment: This IS `Knapsack` if you treat all the different Knapsacks as a single Knapsack it's the same. There are many ways to approximate Knapsack I'm sure you can find them if you do a google search.

Comment: @SinisterRainbow, we don't hate homework. We just hate it when folks don't show they've put out any effort. :)

Comment: Homework? No... I've been out of school for a long time :-) Just a theoretical thought experiment I had when deciding whether or not I could write a program to solve a problem like this. I did some research on matching algorithms which led me to the knapsack problem. This seemed similar to that, but I don't know enough about algorithms to know the best way to approach a problem like this. What else would you like me to provide?

Comment: @twain249: ah yes, sorry, I forgot a very important restriction: items can't necessarily be put into any bag. Essentially their value becomes zero if they are put into a bag they aren't compatible with. You can imagine a general case where each item has a value dependent on its bag, but for my case, its value will either be 0 or it's normal value, depending on the bag.

Comment: @Jonathan M - I stand corrected. (= This require absolute solution? GA would be suitable for this to approximate one. I saw someone with a paper for a 0/1 knapsack: http://www.micsymposium.org/mics_2004/Hristake.pdf

Answer (score 1):

This is called a transportation problem or some variants as bin packing problem.
There is good set of video lectures on youtube by G. Srinivasan on OR problems.
check out LEC 13, 14, and 15
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q31jKiEXxdc - Lec 13